# Using render_template in if statement is a performance disadvantage?

Tags: python, flask

I have a html page called `product.html` which is available under the `myurl.com/slug/` url, it features a lot of information, however a few entries lacks some information, therefore I got errors while trying to load that pages because the missing data.

I could easily solve the problem with an if statement, however I'm afraid that it will slow my website. (I have a column in the database that contains information regarding if the entry has any missing data)

```
@app.route('/<slug>/')
def prod_page(slug):
    prod = getProduct(slug)
    if "full information" in prod.avabiality: # rendered html page if we have all of the details
        return render_template('product.html', product_data1 = prod.title, product_data2 = prod.description) 
    else: # rendered html page if we don't have all of the details
        return render_template('product2.html', product_data1 = prod.title)
```

My question is that will this if statement decrease the speed/performance of my website? For example the page load times. Or it's a common practice to using if statments with the Flask's `render_template` function and there is nothing to worry about because the speed difference is not significant?

---

UPDATE

I have changed the if statment to:

```
try:
    return render_template('product.html', product_data1 = prod.title, product_data2 = prod.description) 
except:
    return render_template('product2.html', product_data1 = prod.title)
```

Maybe it's the best idea to avoid performance issues for the most pages since no strings will be compared. If the first version fails it means I need the second html template, so the second case will load the page properly.

Comment: have you profiled it? (it should be trivial)

Comment: @AnthonySottile what do you mean exactly? I couldn't really make a difference, because localhost is not so fast anyway and I assume the difference can't be measured in 3-4-5 seconds.